# add validation on qty box added with add to cart button on product list?

Tags: magento2, validation

I have added a qty box with add to cart button on product list page like

```
<input type="number" min="1" name="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{'required-number':true,digits:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"/>
```

How I can validate this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tocart').click(function () {
                $Obj = $(this).closest('form');
                if ($Obj.valid()) {
                    $Obj.submit();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```